# How to manage libraries when building projects?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have a project `XXX` that depends on another framework `YYY`. The framework provides a `YYYConfig.cmake`. When I configure my project with `cmake-gui` I add the framework over the `YYY_DIR` variable. I generate and build the solution. Now when I run `XXX.exe` I get an error that a `.dll` from `YYY` couldn't be loaded. The `.lib` libraries and header files are found if I'm right.

Online I've seen that `.dll` have to be put in the same folder where the `.exe` is located in. But why can't I just use the `.dll` that are already present in the installation folder of `YYY`? And is there a way to automatically put all `.dll` that my project needs into the right folder?

I have the feeling that I'm lacking a bit of fundamental knowledge about deployment, so I'd highly appreciate any helpful reference or link about that. Thanks.

---

*Additional information*

I've built a framework, i.e. [*AliceVision*](https://github.com/alicevision/AliceVision) using `vcpkg`, `cmake-gui` and Visual Studio 2019. The folder of the installed framework contains the following folders:

- `bin` with many `.exe` and `.dll`
- `share` where `AliceVisionConfig.cmake` is located in
- `include` with many `.hpp` of the framework and other dependencies
- `lib` with many `.lib`

Now I try to create a simple test project with a `main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <aliceVision/system/cpu.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Total cpus " << aliceVision::system::get_total_cpus() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and a `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

project(AliceVisionAs3rdParty)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(AliceVision CONFIG REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Found AliceVision : ${AliceVision_FOUND}")
message(STATUS "Found AliceVision version: ${AliceVision_VERSION}")

add_executable(testAV3rd main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testAV3rd PUBLIC aliceVision_system)
```

When configuring with `cmake-gui` in the folder of my test project I'm just using a variable `AliceVision_DIR` to point at the folder `AliceVisionConfig.cmake` is located in. I'm using `vcpkg` for the toolchain, which is needed by the framework for some dependencies. Then I'm generating and building the solution. Here is the point where I'm starting the `.exe` and getting the message that a `aliceVision_system.dll` couldn't be found. It is present in the `bin` folder of the framework and as `aliceVision_system.lib` in the `lib` folder. I've checked the `.exe` with [*Dependencies*](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) and yes, it's this `.dll` that is not found. All the Windows `.dll` stuff is found ...

Comment: Review the search-algorithm that Windows uses when finding `.DLL` files.  Make sure that the first project actually creates a `.DLL` versus a `.LIB`.  Please post details to this ticket to help us answer you.

Comment: @MikeRobinson I've added some additional information to describe the case better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide cmake you library:

```
add_library(aliceVision_system SHARED IMPORTED)
```

if the path to this pre-compiled library is not know, evtl. you'll need to try to define `link_directories(path_to_your_library)`.